# Use of Arabic in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arabic

I've been successful in making a database table, which saves Arabic Values. But when I run this Query (Your browser may not correctly display Arabic text):

`SELECT * FROM ar_table WHERE title LIKE '%روشنی%'`

This fails, I get the error:

`#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'`

What should be optimized so I can do such Queries. I need this for Search Form which would search in Arabic fonts.

Please Help.

Comment: Your table is not UTF8 it seems, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right soulseekah. I converted collation of title column to utf8_unicode_ci insteat of latin1_general_ci. It works perfect. Thanks